# Which comic had Batman getting punched by Wonder Woman after he kissed her?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification, wonder-woman

I came across this comic book page on the Internet, I would like to know which comic this page belongs to.

[image: Batman getting punched by Wonder Woman after kissing her]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Batman/Superman/Wonder Woman: Trinity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman/Superman/Wonder_Woman:_Trinity) (2003)

> **Issue 3**
>
> Worried about her, Superman and Batman travel to Themyscira to see how Diana is doing. Breaking off the harness and gliding down, Batman finds Diana after taking her bath. Overcome by her beauty he rushes forward and kisses her, but Diana, surprised, decks the Dark Knight....

Further backup, someone references it in [this Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/810026685?book_show_action=true):

> Batman kissing Wonder Woman then getting punched?? To [sic] damn hilarious.